# How I can clear JRE cache dynamicly in java applet

Tags: applet, java

Here is code:

```
<applet code="ATest.class" archive="ATest.class?v=200406181300">
</applet>
```

I want to clear existing cache and load the new one when it loads 1st time.How can i do in java applet?

I tested it in Firefox 0.9 and it loaded and ran the class. The idea here
    is that when you change the class, you change the [v]ersion in the ARCHIVE
    attribute. That should force the browser to get a new copy of the class
    file, since the "archive" is now at a different URI, and since the
    "archive" is the .class file, it might work (unless the user agent
    disregards ARCHIVEs that are classes, which is entirely possible)

Comment: <applet code="ATest.class" archive="ATest.class?v=200406181300"></applet> how to call it dynamically

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the applet can so this.

But I don't think it needs to either.  If the changing the `v` parameter to a different value isn't sufficient to get the browser to request a new copy of the class, then put it into a JAR file and arrange that the JAR file's name changes each time you want to deploy a fresh version.

---

I should note that forcing the browser to download a fresh copy of a class if it *hasn't* changed is a bad idea.  It won't achieve anything useful.  On the contrary, it will waste server and network resources, and it will make the page load slower.

Comment: <html>    
<body>
<applet width=600 height=300 code="MyClass.class" 
  type="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=6" 
  archive="http://myurl.com/archive/myjar.jar" 
  codebase="http://myurl.com/classes">
    no applet
</applet>
</body>    
</html>

Comment: You need to use a different JAR file name each time you want to force a refetch; e.g. `http://example.com/jar-v1.jar`, `http://example.com/jar-v2.jar` and so on.

Comment: @Manu - nope.  I don't do free coding jobs.

Answer (score 0):

First, read your question: Why would one update an Applet, "when it loads 1st time"? If you mean the second time, when the plugin tries to load it from its own cache, than just use a new codebase, maybe a new one for every visit/or.